# How to cancel a custom javascript event in a listener?

Tags: javascript, events

If a custom event created via `CustomEvent` is dispatched, what is the method to cancel it in listeners to prevent event's main purpose?

***E.g.*** An overlay is clicked by a user, then it emits an event, but it must be up to some code to decide if to hide the overlay or leave it untouched.

**UPDATE** It's a [share-knowledge](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) question, I know the answer but try to impart it to the others.

Comment: Why did you ask a question while you already know the answer yourself? Also it's a duplicate

Comment: @SanderVisser - That (the ask-and-answer part) is **perfectly fine** on SO, and [actively encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). The duplicate part is fine or not fine depending (for self-answer, usually not fine). (Duplicates can help direct people to the already-asked question and its answers.) Please identify the duplicate so people can vote appropriately.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok ok, it's more that the question was asked and the answer 1 sec later. I know that you can answer you own question if you found the answer yourself. But this felt a bit strange.

Comment: @SanderVisser - The system explicitly encourages answering the question **as** you ask it -- e.g., sharing knowledge you already have, but in Q&A form. When you're asking a question, it has a button to press if you want to provide the answer at the same time. Then it publishes both at once.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Didn't know thanks!

Comment: @Sander Visser I was looking for a quick answer here but didn't found any about vanilla JS, then, after own search, decided that I'm not alone and shared the knowledge. Can you give a link with the duplicate? I would ask a moderator to mark my question as a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fire custom cancelable event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732247/how-to-fire-custom-cancelable-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to configure the event as `cancellable`

```
// create an event
let awesomeEvent = new CustomEvent('some_awesome_event', {
    cancelable: true
})
// emit
let isAllowed = window.dispatchEvent(awesomeEvent)
```

Call `preventDefault` inside any event listener to cancel it.

```
window.addEventListener('some_awesome_event', event => {
    event.preventDefault()
})
```

Then it is possible to check whether the event was cancelled with the result returned from `dispatchEvent`

```
let isAllowed = window.dispatchEvent(awesomeEvent)
if(isAllowed){
    // do some default things
}
else {
    // just an example
    console.log('Oops! The event was cancelled, nothing to do...')
}
```

[MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for events creation and triggering

[preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) documentation

[cancellable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable) interface docs